# Why Hibernate session fetching fails in this code piece?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am experimenting with Hibernate 4.1.2.

Wrote the following class to help me get a session using new ServiceRegistry approach

=====================================================

```
package com.debaself.samples;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;


public class SessionFetch {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){

if(sessionFactory == null){
         Configuration cfg = new    AnnotationConfiguration().addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml").configure();

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new     ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    return sessionFactory ;
}

public Session getSession(){
    return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
}
```

===============================================

Now I wrote a test

===============================================

```
public class SessionFetchTest {

    @Test 
    public void getSessionFactoryTest(){
        SessionFetch fetch = new SessionFetch();
        SessionFactory factory = fetch.getSessionFactory();

        assertNotNull(factory);
        assert(!factory.isClosed());
        factory.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void getSessionTest(){
        SessionFetch fetch = new SessionFetch();
        Session session = fetch.getSession();

        assert(session.isOpen());
        assert(session.isConnected());      
    }
}
```

==================================================

The weirdness is

when I run the test methods individually both tests succeed. But when I run them in one go the getSessionTest() invariably fails and throws an UnknownServiceException.

Can anyone explain this behaviour please?

Comment: My first guess is its something to do with the static member of type SessionFactory but still I do not have a definitive answer for this.

Comment: I guess because you close the session factory in your first test ...

Comment: ha ha.. thats interesting and silly at the same time :) thanks Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the factory is closed. Maybe close it in the `@AfterClass` section ?

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate question has already been answered, but note that your code suffers from additional problems. The unit tests are supposed to be executable with no interdependencies, but that is not the case with your code. You reuse the same session across tests. You also reuse the factory and even close it in one test. Also, the tests may be run in several threads and your code is not thread-safe (the factory reference will not be properly shared).

Comment: As you would be able to see I am really not attempting at building some high volume app with these tests. The goal was to simply explore session creation with new ServiceRegistry model and the tests were simplest and quickest way to implement, thats all. Though I shall highly appreciate any insight as to how to avoid the static pattern used to cache the factory. Since I am convinced we won't be creating the factory each time.

Comment: One more point - the sessions are not being reused across the tests whatsoever and the factory needs to be reused to avoid overheads. Any inputs will be highly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Well, as long as you are careful enough, you can reuse the factory. That certainly excludes closing it. You basically have a lazy-initialized singleton. Better make it eagerly initialized and final. Also you probably want to ensure a new session for each test, that can be done by closing it in `tearDown`.

Comment: your comment still doesn't clarify authoritatively if we should recreate the factory. Are you suggesting that we should prefer recreating the factory than to reuse it ?

Comment: You can reuse the factory, yes. I'd probably do the same. It's meant to be created once and kept as a global singleton.